# How do I resolve a missing utility module preventing my executable from running when I already installed the parent module?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pyinstaller, executable

I've written a few Python scripts to create a tkinter GUI for a machine learning algorithm process. I originally coded everything in PyCharm, but I'd really like to put everything together into a stand-alone executable. I've moved my main script and its .py dependencies into their own directory and tested it out using the Command Prompt, and it works great. However, when I run pyinstaller, the executable is created but fails on startup.

The program is made up of three files, with GUI.py being the main script. As mentioned above, I moved the dependent files into a new directory and tested GUI.py in the Command Prompt, and it worked great. Executable is created (albeit with a lot of warnings about missing 'api-ms-win-crt' files) but can't be run.

I created the executable using the command:

```py
pyinstaller --onefile GUI.py
```

When the executable is run from the command line after creation, I get a big long traceback ending in the following:

```py
File "site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py", line 32, in <module>
File "sklearn\metrics\pairwise_fast.pyx", line 1, in init 
    sklearn.metrics.pairwise_fast
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils._cython_blas'
[3372] Failed to execute script GUI
```

I know I've already explicitly imported sklearn through the command prompt, but from the traceback, it seems I'm missing a utility module somewhere. I tried to import the missing module specifically, but I got an error that no distributed module was available. 
I don't have much experience with pyinstaller, and I have no idea where to go from here. I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.7.3.

Comment: Have you tried using `--hidden-import "sklearn.utils._cython_blas"` with your build command?

Comment: That did solve the error above, but it was replaced by yet another 'sklearn.' module missing. I added a few more hidden import arguments, but the ModuleNotFoundError just kept bringing up additional sklearn modules. Do you know of any way to import a module and all of its internal modules? @M.R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Pyinstaller can't resolve `sklearn` import. So one easy way is to just bring the whole module directory which located in `<path_to_python>/Lib/site-packages/sklearn/` with executable output. So use below spec file to generate your executable:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['test.py'],
             pathex=['<path to root of your project>'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
a.datas += Tree('<path_to_sklearn_in_python_dir>', prefix='sklearn')
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='test',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

Finally generate your executable with

```
pyinstaller test.spec
```

This should resolve import errors for `sklearn` but if you face other NotFound imports add them like above to spec file.

Comment: Another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57108026/pyinstaller-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn-utils-cython-blas/57108887#57108887).

Answer (score 0):

Building up on [M.R.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56896907/5190279), you can directly include the path to `sklearn` in your original pyinstaller command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile GUI.py --add-data "<path-to-python>\Lib\site-packages\sklearn;sklearn"
```

which results in the following line of code being added inside `a = Analysis()` in the automatically-generated `GUI.spec` file:

```
datas=[('<path-to-python>\\Lib\\site-packages\\sklearn', 'sklearn')]
```

Note that the `--onefile` option will result in an executable that is slower to start up than the default one-folder bundle (based on both the [pyinstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-file) and my own experience bundling up `sklearn`):

```
pyinstaller GUI.py --add-data "<path-to-python>\Lib\site-packages\sklearn;sklearn"
```