# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors._partition_nodes' with PyInstaller

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pyinstaller

I have been trying to build a Windows executable from Python files using PyInstaller (and auto-py-to-exe, but the problem really resides with PyInstaller). Once the executable is built (using --onedir) , I try to launch it and it crashes with this error message:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\feature_selection\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\feature_selection\_mutual_info.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "sklearn\neighbors\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1050, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "sklearn\neighbors\_ball_tree.pyx", line 1, in init sklearn.neighbors._ball_tree
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.neighbors._partition_nodes'
[17176] Failed to execute script 'Make_Model' due to unhandled exception!
```

I have tried to add sklearn.neighbors._partition_nodes to the hidden imports list, but I still obtain the same error message. I have looked at the very helpful [auto-py-to-exe](https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe/) page and the not-as-helpful [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html) page, but nothing specific to my problem can be found.

I know that scikit-learn is notoriously difficult to deal with when it comes to PyInstaller, but can anybody provide some guidance about this problem?

In case someone asks, the code is written in Python 3.7.11 in a Windows 10 environment.

Comment: Have you tried adding `sklearn.neighbors._partition_nodes` to the hidden import list?

Comment: @NickODell Yes, I stated this in my description after the code section (made a typo: I said inputs instead of imports). Still does not work, that's why I am raising this issue.

Comment: Is the `sklearn.neighbors_partition_nodes` also a typo?

Comment: @NickODell Yes. But I did not forget the dot when adding it to the hidden import list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57108026/pyinstaller-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn-utils-cython-blas

Comment: https://www.codetd.com/en/article/11077374

Comment: @DevilIshere Thanks, but I have also seen these, which repeat the same solutions I have seen in the references I indicated. Since then, I have been able to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this by doing what sometimes is the best solution: I deleted all my previous attempts at building the executable and re-started afresh using solely auto-py-to-exe. This time, adding sklearn.neighbors._partition_nodes to the hidden import list worked. I was then able to move on to the next problem (XGBoost), but there are plenty of answers available for that.